# Open file from explorer always in the current tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

I switched from vim to vscode with vim plugin and I'm pretty happy overall.

When I open a file in vim it will always be the current vim tab, if I wanted a new tab I could do that.

But in vscode I can open a file in preview mode (single click) or permanently (double click). I don't wanna deal with all that. I turned preview mode off and now it always opens a new tab, which can get out of hand pretty quickly.

I searched quite a while but can't seem to find a way to force a rewrite of the current tab.

Comment: Doesn't the preview mode do exactly that, if you always keep your only tab in preview mode?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question (I don't use vim, perhaps that's the reason). Do you mean that you want to configure Visual Studio Code in single document mode, as Windows Notepad?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no, if you change the file and you want to open a new file it will always create a new tab. I want to to default to open the file in the current tab, even after I changed the file.